# Is it possible to make a serverless client-side database program using sqlite and php?

Tags: sqlite, client-side

I have a client who wants a small database program that can run on his personal computer. I've set up multiple mySQL databases in the past, and I prefer to program custom user interfaces using HTML, CSS, and PHP because it allows for a lot of customization. My question would be, is there a feasible way for me to create a client side database program using a SQLITE and HTML,CSS,PHP? Or should I consider another programming language?

*I've considered using a virtual lamp/wamp stack like XAMPP, but I was hoping to find a more efficient means.

I'm open to any ideas.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP 5.4 has a built-in webserver, which means you can develop an application which only dependency would be installing PHP on client machine. (I assume the web browser is already available)

Also, you may want to create a script (batch file) to start the server (and maybe launch the browser). SQLite support is included in default version of PHP.

http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

Comment: Oh wow, I honestly was not aware of that. Thank you very much!